# xslt преобразование. Из soap в xml-rpc

Tags: xml, xslt, преобразование

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, с xslt преобразованием. Необходимо soap

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"<soapenv:Body>
  <GetHospitalReferralListResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <FAM>Смирнова</FAM>
     <IM>Валентина</IM>
     <MO xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
  </GetHospitalReferralListResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Необходимо преобразовать в :

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='cp1251'?><methodCall><methodName>hospitaliz_add_referral</methodName><params><param><value><struct><member><name>FAM</name><value><string>Смирнова</string></value></member><member><name>IM</name><value>Валентина<string></string></value></member></struct></value></param></params></methodCall>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятна суть вопроса. Вам из `soap` формата нужно преобразовать в `xml-rpc` запрос? В чём тогда проблема погуглить ваш вопрос? Парсите ваш `soap`, формируете `xml` нужной структуры.

Comment: хороший ответ. Наверное, он мне очень поможет

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы вам полностью написали функцию, которая это будет делать? На каком языке программирования? Вы парсить ваш `soap` будете на сервере, или на клиенте? Вы ведь никакой информации не указали, чтобы вам помочь, да и вопросом видимо не занимались. Если бы вы работали в этом направлении - ваш вопрос был бы не 'как это сделать', а 'я пытаюсь сделать вот это, но оно не работает, как заставить его работать или какие пути решение есть еще'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<GetHospitalReferralListResponse  xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <FAM>Смирнова</FAM>
    <IM>Валентина</IM>
</GetHospitalReferralListResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

вот так получилось

```
   <?xml  version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org"
                xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xmlns:ref="http://tempuri.org/">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xml>
            <xsl:for-each select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ref:GetHospitalReferralListResponse">
                <methodCall><methodName>add</methodName>
                    <params><param><value><struct>
                        <member><name>FAM</name><value><string> <xsl:value-of select="ref:FAM"/></string></value></member>
                        <member><name>IM</name><value><string> <xsl:value-of select="ref:IM"/></string></value></member>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xml>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Результат:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org"
     xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ref="http://tempuri.org/">
    <methodCall>
        <methodName>add</methodName>
        <params>
            <param>
                <value>
                    <struct>                     
                        <member>
                            <name>FAM</name>
                            <value>
                                <string>Смирнова</string>
                            </value>
                        </member>
                        <member>
                            <name>IM</name>
                            <value>
                                <string>Валентина</string>
                            </value>
                        </member>
                    </struct>
                </value>
            </param>
        </params>
    </methodCall>
</xml>
```